# How to configure mapproxy and mapnik for getfeatureinfo requests

Tags: mapnik, getfeatureinfo, mapproxy

I'm wondering if its possible to configure `mapproxy` and `mapnik` for `getfeatureinfo` requests. I've made this combination work for `getmap` requests, but when I request `getfeatureinfo` I receive `layer xxx is not queryable`. I've tried setting `featureinfo:true`, but no luck there.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Put `queryable="true"` in your Mapnik XML for that layer. It is by design that layers are not queryable by default.

Comment: ancient answer I know... I've added here: <Layer name="bathy" srs="+init=epsg:3857" queryable="true">, also added "queryable: true" to the source in the mapproxy yaml (although no mention of this option in the docs). Restarted but no luck, it doesn't show as queryable in mapproxy getCapabilities. While it seems its possible in mapnik, I dont think mapproxy knows how to handle/forward the request for mapnik sources.