# Configuring Mapproxy + Mapnik for using Getfeatureinfo

Tags: mapnik, getfeatureinfo, mapproxy

This is probably a duplicate of this question: [How to configure mapproxy and mapnik for getfeatureinfo requests](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/58344/how-to-configure-mapproxy-and-mapnik-for-getfeatureinfo-requests), however, that one is old and still unanswered.

I'm trying to configure a Mapproxy using Mapnik and I need to make getfeatureinfo requests available.

My configuration files are like this (parts that I believe are relevant):

mapproxy.yaml:

```
services:
  demo:
  kml:
  tms:
  wmts:
  wms:
    srs: ['EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:900913']
    image_formats: ['image/jpeg', 'image/png']

layers:
  - name: poi
    title: Pleno POIs
    sources: ['poi_wms']
  - name: vias
    title: Pleno Vias
    sources: ['vias_wms']

sources:
  poi_wms:
    type: mapnik
    mapfile: mapnik/Mapnik.xml
    transparent: true
    layers: ['poi']
  vias_wms:
    type: mapnik
    mapfile: mapnik/Mapnik.xml
    transparent: true
    layers: ['vias']
```

And my mapnik xml looks like this:

```
<Map ...>
   <Style>...</Style>

   <Layer name="vias"
           srs="+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0.0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext +no_defs +over"
           queryable="true">
        <StyleName>vias</StyleName>
        <Datasource>
            (...)
        </Datasource>
    </Layer>

    <Layer name="poi"
           srs="+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0.0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext +no_defs +over"
           queryable="true">
        <StyleName>poi</StyleName>
        <Datasource>
            (...)
        </Datasource>
    </Layer>
</Map>
```

When I try to do a getfeatureinfo request, I get `"layer vias is not queryable"`.

I've tried adding the `queryable="true"`, as one answer in old question I've linked suggested and had no success.

Also, I had one layer on mapproxy using the 2 layers on mapnik, I changed to two to see if it would matter, still nothing.

I'm using Mapproxy 1.5 and on its documentation (http://mapproxy.org/docs/1.5.0/sources.html) it says how to make a wms source queryable (add `wms_opts: featureinfo: true`). The problem is that it only works if you have `type: wms`. When you have `type: mapnik`, it says that the keys wms_opts or featureinfo are unknow and it doesn't work.

I've tried several other stuff (like adding a key `mapnik_opts` with `featureinfo: true`) and couldn't get it to work, nor find any information about this on the web.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem? (Or at least have some kind of workaround for it?)
It seems like either mapproxy doesn't support getfeatureinfo requests when you're using mapnik or the information about how to do it is well hidden. :(